# Can I reshuffle data in nested tibble in R?

Tags: r, random, nested-lists

I want to be able to randomize when ("date.time") a "type" occurred for each "pair", and ultimately repeat this process 10,000 for a permutation reference model.

As I was looking for solutions, I came across [this](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls12_different-sized-samples.html) example for inspiration. I was under the impression that this code would resample the tibble with the appropriate number of types/date.times for each pair.

I am thinking I am misunderstanding what the n_sample() function does, and I have a limited understanding of how to manipulate nested data. Instead of reshuffling the order of that type and date.time occurs within the tibble, **I would like to reassign a random date.time to a type for each pair. It is important that the type and date.time are specific to the particular pair**.

Below is a simplified attempt for one iteration of my for-loop:

I have a df like this:

```
df <- data.frame(pair=c("AB", "AB", "AB", "AB", "CD", "CD", "DE", "DE", "DE"), 
                 type=c("PR", "NN", "AP", "PX", "BK", "PX", "NN", "NN", "S2"),
                 date.time=c("2021-04-05_17:50:42", "2021-04-05_17:00:03", "2021-04-05_15:36:00", "2021-04-05_15:20:13", "2021-04-05_16:40:14", "2021-04-05_16:11:21", "2021-04-05_17:00:03", "2021-04-05_16:40:14", "2021-04-05_17:00:03"))
```

I identified the number of "samples" for each pair or the number of types that occurred:

```
sample.sizes <- df  %>% 
                  dplyr::group_by(pair) %>%  
                  dplyr::summarize(n.sample = n()) %>%
                  ungroup()
```

I nested the data and drew samples:

```
nested_data <- df  %>%
       select(pair, type, date.time) %>%
       group_by(pair) %>%   
       nest() %>%  # --> one row per relationship
       ungroup() %>% 
       arrange(pair) %>%
       merge(sample.sizes, by = "pair")


 sampled_obsdata <- nested_obsdata %>%
                  mutate(sample = purrr::map2(data, n.sample, n_sample))

data <- sampled_obsdata %>% 
                          select(-data) %>%
                          unnest(sample) %>%
                          arrange(pair, date.time)
```

I hope my problem and ideal outcome is clear - I'm a first time poster, so go easy on me! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think I hear you saying that you want to generate a new date.time value from a randomly sampled value within the same pair group, so where pair is "AB" there are 4 values, any of which can be chosen for a new date.time value for each row that has "AB" as pair? If so, you can group_by pair and mutate and sample to create a new variable that has sampled from that group. It is unclear if each new date.time value has to be unique or if it can repeat and if it is ok if the old date.time and new date.time can be the same. Assuming these are not constraints, you can do:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% group_by(pair) %>% mutate(new_date = sample(date.time)) %>% ungroup
```

which gives something like:

```
# A tibble: 9 × 4
  pair  type  date.time           new_date           
  <chr> <chr> <chr>               <chr>              
1 AB    PR    2021-04-05_17:50:42 2021-04-05_17:00:03
2 AB    NN    2021-04-05_17:00:03 2021-04-05_15:36:00
3 AB    AP    2021-04-05_15:36:00 2021-04-05_17:50:42
4 AB    PX    2021-04-05_15:20:13 2021-04-05_15:20:13
5 CD    BK    2021-04-05_16:40:14 2021-04-05_16:11:21
6 CD    PX    2021-04-05_16:11:21 2021-04-05_16:40:14
7 DE    NN    2021-04-05_17:00:03 2021-04-05_16:40:14
8 DE    NN    2021-04-05_16:40:14 2021-04-05_17:00:03
9 DE    S2    2021-04-05_17:00:03 2021-04-05_17:00:03
```

**EDIT:**
Based on comments below, to not have any repeated new dates in a group and not have a new_date match date.time, you can sample then re-sample until constraints are met. Based on how big your data is and how many groups, you could nest by pair then iterate through until the condition is met for each group. If your data is more complicated, I'd retain a group of date.time values for each group, then go row-by-row and remove each value sampled, not allowing the sample value to match the date.time value, otherwise this will take a while as it's unlikely you'd not get a matching new and old date value in at least one row in the group.

The following shows how to do for the whole data. As noted in comments, your constraints are impossible with group DE, which has data that guarantees a new_date matches an date.time. I filtered out:

```
partial_df <- df %>% filter(pair != "DE")
repeat({
    # Sample date.time for each group a shown,
    partial_df <- partial_df %>% 
        group_by(pair) %>% 
        mutate(new_date = sample(date.time)) %>% 
        ungroup()
    
    #  then break when all the new_date values do not match date.time
    if(partial_df %>% summarise(all(new_date != date.time)) %>% pull()){
        # add return(df) here if nesting, and just include mutate above
        break()
    } 
})
```

Comment: Thanks for this and the clarifying questions! This looks like a great solution to my problem. I want to sample without replacement, so once a date.time has been sampled, it cannot be sampled again for a particular pair group. I think I can accomplish this with replace = FALSE? If I wanted to ensure the old and new date.times could not be the same, how could I accomplish that?

Comment: As your data is, it's not possible to get a new_date value that doesn't match date.time because in group DE there are two date.time values that are the same out of three values, which guarantees one date.time value will always match the new_date. Yes, to sample without replacement set replace = FALSE, which is default. I edited my answer to show a way to meet the additional constraints.

Comment: Thanks for the update, but I am running into the same problem I had before which is why I am using the nested data solution. I think issues arise because I need a different number of samples per pair. I am wondering if you know how edit my code so that it samples only the date.time column within the nested data rather than sampling all rows. I am not familiar with the structure enough to successfully get the sampled data from the current format.